# Understanding how MobaXterm keeps an ssh connection alive

Tags: ssh, encryption, tcp, mobaxterm

I want to have a stable ssh connection to a server where I do things. That would last for days or weeks.

In general, one can set TCP keepalive to more than 7200 seconds:

[Socket reset by peer ever 2 hours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377231/socket-reset-by-peer-ever-2-hours)

In MobaXterm, there are two checkboxes for maintaining a stable connection:

- Enable SSH keepalive (send data every 60 seconds to avoid disconnections)
- Workaround for "connection reset by peer" issue (stripped-down encryption algorithms list)

I used the first and my connection was "reset by peer".

Today I realised that I should use the second as well to keep my ssh connection alive for a day.

But what is this *workaround* ?

What this has anything to do with *encryption algorithms* ?

Comment: I have the same problem,`Enable SSH Keepalive` still got ssh disconnect sometimes. where did you find the checkbox `Workaround for "connection reset by peer" issue`  ?

Comment: @ValiantJiang It's now labeled as `Fix Connection Issues`, and default checked for me.  It's in the same place as the `SSH keepalive` config (app settings -> SSH tab -> SSH settings box)

Comment: In 2021 version, v21.2 build 4642, there are not any settings with name "Fix connection issues" :( https://i.ibb.co/1RzH9r6/Moba-Xterm-Configuration.png